# Cannot start GUI applications “Error: cannot open display: :0”

Tags: linux-mint, xorg

I am getting this error when trying to launch Thunderbird (or any other program, such as evince):

```
❯ thunderbird
Unable to init server: Unable to create socket: Permission denied
Error: cannot open display: :0

❯ thunderbird -v
Thunderbird 68.10.0
```

Any ideas?

```
❯ cat /etc/linuxmint/info
RELEASE=20
CODENAME=ulyana
EDITION="Cinnamon"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 20 Ulyana"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_ulyana_cinnamon_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_ulyana_cinnamon.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/documentation.php
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon
```

Comment: Have you switched user?

Comment: Hi. I just have one user on this machine.

Comment: Either you're trying to start them from a different user account or root. In short logoff/logon and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I have rebooted several times and still have this problem. Note that I am able to launch some other applications such as evolution from command line.

Comment: Does `xclock` work for you from the terminal that you're using?

Comment: Yes it works. It shows a small clock.

Comment: And what does return echo $DISPLAY in the same terminal ? Perhaps thunderbird has a setup script that redirect you to :0 which you aren't using. I would test > echo $DISPLAY, then export DISPLAY=:0.0 then launch thunderbird.

Comment: ❯ echo $DISPLAY :0 I have tried to export as: export DISPLAY=0:0 still no luck.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but: "xdpyinfo | grep display
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "0:0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a solution (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1433165):

```
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.thunderbird
```

I do not understand what it does, but I am now able to start both evince and thunderbird.

Comment: 2023 here and yet it works!